# Link still clickable after .hide()

Tags: jquery, html, css

My links at the Games-div are still clickable after it has been hidden with the .hide() function of jQuery. How can I edit it so that they aren't clickable anymore?

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hypertje/Frv8G/

```
PS: my images and background aren't visible due to files being on my computer.
```

Comment: The downvotes are because the question is useless without going to the link. 1. people including me don't like to search for the code. 2. the question will be useless for others if the link dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a mistake inside your script. Check this: [jsfiddle.net/Frv8G/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Frv8G/1/)

I changed "s-o" to "g-o".

```
$("#containergames").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".g-o").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, function () {
        $(".g-o").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the anchor. You are just removing the image, but that area is still clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on line 46 of your JS code:

```
 $(".s-o").hide();
```

should be

```
 $(".g-o").hide();
```

But unless this is simply a learning exercise for javascript, I would suggest using CSS for your menu rather than JS.  When possible of course, I believe it's important that core functionality of a website doesn't rely on Javascript.   You can make the same menu(but with a mouseover rather than a click) with pure css that is supported in virtually all major browsers.